# Passing default values to a column in Bulk insert

Tags: sql, t-sql

I am trying to get data from a csv file with the following data.

```
Station code;Priority vehicle;DateBegin;DateEnd
01;y;20100214;20100214
02;n;20100214;20100214
03;;20100214;20100214
```

Now I want a value 'n' in the table when no data is provided for the column 'Priority vehicle' in csv file.
I am writing the query as

```
BULK INSERT dbo.#tmp_station_details  
    FROM 'C:\station.csv'  
    WITH (  
         FIELDTERMINATOR ='';'',  
         FIRSTROW = 2,
         ROWTERMINATOR = ''\n'' 
        )
```

Answer (score 1):

Check the full explanation here: 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187887.aspx

"*By default, when data is imported into a table, the bcp command and **BULK INSERT statement** observe any defaults that are defined for the columns in the table. For example, if there is a null field in a data file, the default value for the column is loaded instead.* "

My suggestion is to specify a default value for the **Priority vehicle** column and the Null value from the csv file will be overwritten to your SQL table with the default value specified in the table design.