# .NET SqlBulkCopy - can Null-able fields be excluded

Tags: .net, sqlbulkcopy

I small app that uploads data from CSV file to the cloud. This app runs at on several servers and each of these servers produces such a file.

My app incrementally import data from this CSV file into a datatable and using SqlBulkCopy bulk load it to Azure SQL.

Currently the table in Azure SQL matches the CSV file layout.

Azure SQL Table

```
CREATE TABLE stg.EventLog(
EventLogID BIGINT PRIMARY KEY,
EventLogDate DATETIME NOT NULL,
EventName VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
EventType VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL    
)
```

However one server wants to modify their CSV file to contain a additional field. So I have to create the additional column and ensure it can accept a NULL value.

Update to the table will then be:

```
ALTER TABLE stg.EventLog ADD Comments VARCHAR(1024) NULL
```

My apps original sync code looks as follow:

```
bc = New SqlBulkCopy(cnn)

bc.DestinationTableName = "dbo.EventLog"
bc.BatchSize = 10000

bc.ColumnMappings.Add("LogID", "LogID")
bc.ColumnMappings.Add("LogDate", "LogDate")
bc.ColumnMappings.Add("EventName", "EventName")
bc.ColumnMappings.Add("EventType", "EventType")

bc.WriteToServer(dt)
```

Now here is the weird tricky part. I cant update the app on the other servers until end of Feb 2021 due to corporate red tape. But I have to update the server with the change in CSV file structure ASAP. This means I need to add the additional column mapping to the app, build and deploy it.

**So my question is:** Based on the .NET code above, will it still work on the other servers if the Destination Table contains a NULLable field that is not mapped with SqlBulkCopy?

Please let me know if more info is needed.

Comment: Is there a reason you're using `varchar` instead of `nvarchar` for a field that looks like it will contain human-written text?

Comment: @dai Well the "comment" is basically a system built string of additional information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it will work. But you need to make sure you don't use `SqlBulkCOpyOPtions.KeepNulls`, and the column must have a default. In this case you already have `NULL`. For `NOT NULL` columns, you need a default. See further [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27027013/sqlbulkcopy-into-table-that-default-column-values-fails-when-source-datatable-ro).

From [MSDN docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopycolumnmapping?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0#remarks) for `SqlBulkCopyColumnMapping` class:

> If the ColumnMappings collection is not empty, not every column present in the data source has to be specified. Those not mapped by the collection are ignored.

---

Incidentally, some tips for `SqlBulkCopy`:

1. You must dispose it with `using`
2. Test different batch sizes, it can make a difference to performance.
3. `SqlDataRecord` is faster and use less client RAM, especially if you're streaming from an `IEnumerable`, but it can be more complex. If you already have a `DataTable` don't bother.
4. Consider using `SqlBulkCopyOptions.TableLock`